# gem 1.8.23 install rails 3.2.8 failed, Unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation

I'm trying to install Rails 3.2.8 to a linux box without internet connection. I've manually downloaded all the related gem packages and copied them to the linux box. When I try to install some of those packages, I got error. e.g., :

```
[jw@web gems]$ sudo /usr/local/bin/gem install --local ./activemodel-3.2.8.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: activemodel requires builder (~> 3.0.0)
```

The strange thing is that some packages can be installed this way. e.g., the *builder* has already been installed. Please note that all the dependencies required are there.

How come the dependencies is unable to resolve ?

My environment:

```
Ruby: ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
Rubygem: 1.8.23
```

My installed gems:

```
[jw07@web gems]$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (3.2.8)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.1.3)
bundler (1.2.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.7.5)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.3.6)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
sprockets (2.5.0)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not look like Rubygems version is a problem.

You see rails requires gem builder ~> 3.0.0, but you have 3.1.3 which does not match (`~>` means it will match 3.0.x, but not 3.1.x). You have to install builder 3.0.3.

Another possibility could be there is another gem in your Gemfile that requires builder 3.1.x, causing a conflict. It would be helpful if you provided your Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks a million! changing to builder 3.0.3 get it done. BTW, could you please elaborate on the _~>_ stuff a little bit more ?  like what does it mean ***~> 2.1.3***

Comment: It means the last digit of gem version can be same or larger but others should match exactly. **~> 2.1.3** will match 2.1.3, 2.1.4 and so on, but will not match 2.2.x, 2.3.x etc.

It can be also used like **~> 2.1**. This will match 2.x.x, but not 3.x.x

http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16#page74

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade to the latest RubyGems:

```
gem update --system
```

And install rails with dependencies:

```
gem install rails --include-dependencies
```

Comment: Topic starter says there is no internet connection on this box. Additionally rubygems 1.8.23 is not that old (only one patch older than current). For me rails works perfectly with rubygems 1.8.11.